# Insert using Foreach

Tags: php, mysql

I am not really familiar with array.

I try to save my data to database but its seem not working the only it save was
please check my sample image.

[image: Fields]

and the database it only save was

[image: DB]

and it loop 4times

my codes below

```
<form method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>F Name</td>
        <td>M Name</td>
        <td>L Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="fname" value="" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="mname" value="" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="lname" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="fname" value="" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="mname" value="" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="lname" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br />
<input type="submit" name="SubmitText" value="Save" />
</form>

if ( isset( $_POST['SubmitText'] ) ) {
    $fn = $_POST['fname'];
    $mn = $_POST['mname'];
    $ln = $_POST['lname'];
    $value = array();

    foreach( $_POST as $keys => $value)
    $db = mysql_query( "INSERT INTO jon_test VALUE( '', '".$value['fn']."', '".$value['mn']."', '".$value['ln']."' )" );

    echo $value['fn'] . '<br />';
    echo $db == true ? 'Yes' : 'No';
}
```

is there anything wrong with my codes?

Comment: input name are the same so u get only the last result

Comment: *Obligatory:* The `mysql_*` functions will be [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: How about everything. Everything is wrong with your code. 1. you're not escaping your strings, enabling sql injections. 2. you don't indent your code making it unreadable and thus prone to errors. 3. you're using mysql_* functions which are deprecated. Use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: thank you for your adviced sir Jason McCreary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>F Name</td>
        <td>M Name</td>
        <td>L Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="input[0][fname]" value="" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="input[0][mname]" value="" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="input[0][lname]" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td><input type="text" name="input[1][fname]" value="" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="input[1][mname]" value="" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="input[1][lname]" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br />
<input type="submit" name="SubmitText" value="Save" />
</form>
```

After that you will need to iteratate the post parameters:

```
foreach($_POST['input'] as $input) {
    $db = mysql_query( "INSERT INTO jon_test VALUE( '', '".$input['fname']."', '".$input['mname']."', '".$input['lname']."' )" );

   echo $input['fname'] . '<br />';
   echo $db == true ? 'Yes' : 'No';
}
```

Comment: @user1538668 your code is vulnerable to sql injections, it's good if you use PDO or Mysqli with prepared statements to escape the values before they are inserted in the database. http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: yes i have class of mysqli its just that i used this mysql for test only. sorry next time i will post my class for mysqli

Comment: thank you I apply it to my system, it works not on my WebShop @lexmihaylov

Comment: sorry don't think i understood you right, so it is NOT working on your website. If that is the case could you post some code that we could review

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your PHP code within `<?php ?>` tags like this:

```
<?php
if ( isset( $_POST['SubmitText'] ) ) {
    $fn = $_POST['fname'];
    $mn = $_POST['mname'];
    $ln = $_POST['lname'];
    $value = array();

    foreach( $_POST as $keys => $value)
    $db = mysql_query( "INSERT INTO jon_test VALUE( '', '".$value['fn']."', '".$value['mn']."', '".$value['ln']."' )" );

    echo $value['fn'] . '<br />';
    echo $db == true ? 'Yes' : 'No';
}
?>
```

Also, i recommend you use `mysqli_*` functions instead of `mysql_*` functions, because `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and will be removed in the futere.

Comment: I think the OP knows that already, maybe he forgot to type the tags in the questions. He managed to insert a few things to the database already.

Answer (score 1):

input name are the same so you get only the last result use [] to create an array of values